# selectelement.options return an empty list in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to make automatization in new user creation on IP cameras through the WEB interface, but I can't get options from a "Select" element.
element.options return an empty list, element.select_by_value() raise exception "NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with value: %s" % value)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: 21".
The same results with finding element by XPATH(element = Select(wb.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='index_id']")))
Thanks for any help.

HTML object description:

```
<span>
<select name="index" id="index_id" onchange="onchangeUserList()" style="width:150px;position: absolute;left: 30px;">
<option value="0">username0</option>
<option value="1">username1</option>
<option value="21">--New user--</option>
<option value="22">--Select a user type--</option>
</select> 
</span>
```

part of my python code:

```
wb = webdriver.Chrome()
wb.get(address)
element = Select(wb.find_element(By.NAME, 'index'))
print(element.options)
element.select_by_value('21')
```

Comment: If I run the code on the locally saved page(from the IP camera WEB interface) it works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with `driver.implicitly_wait()`.

More information [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).